# How to Rename a file on S3 bucket after save using 'aws-sdk'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip, aws-sdk

I'm trying to update a file name saved on aws s3 using below code

```
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.3'

creds = Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])

s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(credentials: creds, region: ENV['AWS_REGION'])

bucket = s3.bucket(ENV['AWS_S3_BUCKET'])

filename = URI.unescape(document.url).split('/').last

new_file = 'new_file_name'

obj = bucket.object(filename) # create object of original file name

obj.move_to("#{bucket.name}/#{new_file}", acl: 'public-read')

obj = bucket.object(new_file)
```

when updating giving an error on line `obj.move_to("#{bucket.name}/#{new_file}", acl: 'public-read')`:

```
Aws::S3::Errors::NoSuchKey 
The specified key does not exist.
```

Any suggestions or ideas how to rename a file on s3?

object.inspect output: 
[image]

Thanks

Comment: What is the output of this (placed before your erring line)?: `puts obj.inspect`

Comment: obj.inspect output: "#<Aws::S3::Object bucket_name=\"bucket_name\", key=\"etats_des_stands__copie.pdf?1513753985\">"

Comment: Where are you getting this name? `?1513753985` looks like a query string, not part of the object key.

Comment: @michael - sqlbot Don't know this timestamp is appended by aws with every url

Comment: Something other than AWS is doing that.

Comment: No. only with AWS

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to move an object with key `x` to key `nil`. Given your error I would try initializing a new object `y` first then call the move_to on it.